# nginx won't listen on non-standard port

Tags: nginx, port, 301-redirect

My organization has a server that is just for handling redirects of retired sites (redirects-myorg.org). We've just retired a website (widgets.org), and I am adding the retired site to our redirects server. About a week ago, we had the CNAME record for widgets.org changed so that it points to redirects-myorg.org.

Most of the URLs that were in circulation for widgets.org looked something like: widgets.org:8180/more/info. The 8180 port was explicitly included in the URL.

**Success looks like:**

- Typing widgets.org into a browser: redirects to blue-server.com.
- Typing widgets.org:8180 into a browser: redirects to purple-server.com

(For additional context: Three other sites' redirects are managed on this redirects server, and their configuration files reference ports 80 and 443. None of those sites use non-standard ports like 8180.)

**Attempts**

**1.
I first set up the nginx configuration files to list to ports 80 and 8180 and return a 301 redirect on each:**

```
server {
        listen 8180;
        listen [::]:8180;
        server_name widgets.org;
        return 301 https://purple-server.com;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name widgets.org;
        return 301 https://blue-server.com;
}
```

**Result**:

- Typing widgets.org into a browser: redirects to blue-server.com. Good.
- Typing widgets.org:8180 into a browser: hangs and eventually times not. Not so good.

**2.
Tried switching the order, unsuccessfully:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name widgets.org;
        return 301 https://blue-server.com;
}
server {
        listen 8180;
        listen [::]:8180;
        server_name widgets.org;
        return 301 https://purple-server.com;
}
```

**Result**:

- Same as above.

**3.
Tried tricking nginx, unsuccessfully:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name widgets.org:8180;
        return 301 https://purple-server.com;
}
```

**Result:**

- Typing widgets.org into a browser: "Welcome to nginx!" page. Not so good.
- Typing widgets.org:8180 into a browser: hangs and eventually times not. Not so good.

**4.
Tried tricking nginx a different way, unsuccessfully:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name widgets.org;
        rewrite ^:8180.* https://purple-server.com break;
        return 301 https://blue-server.com;
}
```

**Result:**

- Typing widgets.org into a browser redirects to blue-server.com. Good.
- Typing widgets.org:8180 into a browser hangs and eventually times not. Not so good.

Comment: Did you restart nginx after making the changes? Is nginx actually listening on that ports? Are any errors about the ports in the log files of nginx?

Comment: Please be aware that a Permanent Redirect (a redirect with HTTP response code 301) is exactly that: permanent. Such **a redirect will be cached by all common web browsers**. - If you made a mistake in your server configuration and don't clear your caches (or don't do each new test in a new anonymous/incognito/private window) then any changes you make in the server configuration won't become apparent as your webbrowser will both use the stale cached redirect and change the request you enter in the URL bar for you even before it gets sent to a server.

Comment: Did you check if the port is opened by nginx? Can you show the output of `netstat -anp | grep :8180`

Comment: Also note that a timeout usually points to a firewall issue. Since all your requests to `8180` time out I assume that you forgot to open the port in your firewall.

Comment: That's a firewall problem, most likely. Go there first.

Comment: I use an incognito window with cache cleared to test, so I don't think it's the permanent 301 issue. I have tested if other changes are taking effect, and they do. Thanks, and let me know if there's more on that front I'm not thinking of @hbruijn